# adb reboot device not found message when installing google play services ion gennymotion virtual machine

Tags: android, adb, virtual, genymotion, reboot

I have found a lot of threads on physical devices connected via USB, but I have a gennymotion virtual machine running in Ubuntu.  Just installed Ubuntu and 1st time ever using linux, but I remember the days of dos 6.2 and the command prompt.  For the life of me cannot get adb reboot to work.  I drop the Arm Translation Installer file to the android\gennymotion window and it installs.  Then I can't figure out how to reboot.  I installed abd tools twice in the 2 directories:

/home/db/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/

/home/db/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom\ Tablet\ -\ 4.3\ -\ API\ 18\ -\ 2560x1600/

I try to run from the ubuntu terminal:

adb reboot

adb reboot /home/db/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom\ Tablet\ -\ 4.3\ -\ API\ 18\ -\ 2560x1600/

Each time I get no device found. What am I doing wrong?  I am trying to run the new sling.tv apk and a few other thinkgs and I think I'm getting error messages because I'm not rebooting properly after I install the ARM translator and before I install the Google Play Services GApps file.

Comment: You can reboot by manually closing GenyMotion virtual device window. Not the best way but it works

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and was  getting errors, e.g. when I tried using netflix for example or that sling.tv apk.  i had assumed my issue was not using adb reboot.  Why is it not the "best way", does it prevent proper installation or corruption of the install?

Comment: I don't think so. I've followed http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952 and it works. It could be that you don't have correctly install gapps, but if you have the Play store working AND Google play services updated, It can be something else. 

Also you should know that genyMotion is really not good at video playback, for this part try on a physic phone.